# require_once() Error in linux (apache2)

Tags: php

While i try to deploy the code devloped on wamp server on the dev machine on linux , 
i get this error:
Warning: require_once(**/PHP file**) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/proj/index.php on line 38

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '**/PHP file**' (include_path='.:/var/www/proj:/var/www/proj/framework:') in /var/www/proj/index.php on line 38

Now the PHP file i called is in the path "*/var/www/proj/framework*"

Answer (score 1):

You have just supplied wrong filename.
Use proper path to this PHP file

Comment: @Nauman that IS the case. Because PHP has checked it. And told you so.

Answer (score 1):

```
require_once("/PHP file")
```

is using an absolute path and looking for PHP file in the server's filesystem root directory

```
require_once("./PHP file")
```

or

```
require_once("PHP file")
```

is a relative path that would search for PHP file using the include path

Comment: well that was the case.. actually the wamp server overlooked the / in the command : require_once(/PHP file), i removed the / for the linux server n it worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also, to necromance this thread even further, don't forget Windows doesn't care about case-sensitivity, and Unix/Linux does!

Answer (score 0):

This work for me, using the magic const of PHP

```
require once __DIR__ . "/directory/name_file.php";
```

Answer (score -1):

I have also faced the same problem earlier.
I found on my program that, all path was included using "\" on Windows system and linux supports "/" path separator.
Please check once that all you include path is having "/" path separator.